# Using Range as Criteria in Countif

Tags: arrays, excel, count, sum

I am looking to to use a range as a criteria for a countifs so that when the range matches any combination of the criteria range, it'll count. This is to substitute complex long countifs that are added together. any help? i attempted an array but probably failed

sample {=COUNTIFS(A:A,$F2:$F10,B:B,$G2:G10,C:C,$H2:H10)} 
^ this formula otherwise would be a complex countifs(A:A,F2,B:B,G2,C:C,H2)+....

thank you

Comment: COUNTIFS does not work that way, unfortunately.  You could do a helper column with `=COUNTIFS(A:A,F2,B:B,G2,C:C,H2)` in I2 and copied down then sum at the bottom, or do your large formula.

Comment: What if you wrap the COUNTIFS into a SUM in your array formula?